# Emojis not shown in gtk(?) but in kde applications using the same font

Tags: vim, gtk, gnome

I noticed that Emojis like  are not displayed in gvim on my system but they are in terminal vim if that is used in an xterm or konsole. And yes I tried many `guifont`s capable of displaying them (noto mono, noto color emoji, hack). I also noticed that vim in gnome-terminal doesn't display them either (although using the same fonts in it as in the other terminals). In fact I haven't found a single gnome(?) or gtk(?) application that displays them - not even when I use a gnome X-session. On the other hand no kde app has problems with them. Searching the web I got the impression that, e.g. gnome-terminal should have been able to display emojis for quite some time now. As I use a rolling distribution (openSuse tumbleweed) my software should be pretty recent. So what am I missing? Is there a specific package I need to handle emojis in gtk?

**Update**
I created test user on my system with default settings. To my big surprise if I log on to the X-system as that user emojis are displayed just fine in gvim. So it must be a configuration issue. Then I went back and logged into my normal account, used `su testuser` and then opened gvim. I could still see the emojis. I don't want to reset my configuration as I put a lot of effort to have the system behave the way I like it to. But I am at a loss in finding the responsible setting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the culprit and wanted to share my insight here so that others with similar problems know where to look. In ~/.config/fontconfig/ there were three files I did not put there myself. I guess they were leftovers from some configuration tool. Using a rolling release distribution there are probably many orphaned files in my ~/.config directory. Anyway, after deleting those files and logging out and back on I can now see emojis in gvim etc.